# Optimize courier imap-ssl server configuration for large Emails

Tags: email, courier

I use Courier with postfix on debian 11 and it all works fine, except, I cannot copy large emails into the IMAP Sent Folder.

I cannot find the richt configuration files and options, where I set the maximum email-size for Courier IMAP

Answer (score 0):

The Courier mail server uses several configuration files which are located in

```
/etc/courier
```

you must run courier restart for any changes to these files to take effect.

so this sets the limit to 99MB:

```
echo "99428800" > /etc/courier/sizelimit
service courier-imap-ssl restart
```

see: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/courier.8.html